# I am not able to check Multiple radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Its Question and Four Options and check any one. **Problem** When Checked button to Next Question then previous check was unchecked.

Code as bellow:

```
    <form method="post" id="submitme">
    <table class="ques_list" border=1 style="width:100%">
    <?php 
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row['ques_title']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value" value="1" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_1']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value" value="2" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_2']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value" value="3" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_3']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value" value="4" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_4']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="btn-submit" class="btn-submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And How can i get his value ?
Suggest me.
Thanks.

Comment: That's how radio buttons work.  In any given group of radio buttons, only *one* can be selected.  Maybe you're looking for checkboxes instead?

Comment: That's what radio buttons with the same name does, it becomes a group. If you don't want that, give them different names, or use checkboxes, which would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an index to the names of the radio buttons.

```
<form method="post" id="submitme">
    <table class="ques_list" border=1 style="width:100%">
    <?php 
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row['ques_title']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value_<?php echo $row['ques_id']; ?>" value="1" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_1']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value_<?php echo $row['ques_id']; ?>" value="2" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_2']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value_<?php echo $row['ques_id']; ?>" value="3" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_3']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value_<?php echo $row['ques_id']; ?>" value="4" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_4']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="btn-submit" class="btn-submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

---

*Edit:*

Then you can read your answers as follows:
(`$row['ques_id']`has to be unique for each question and the answers should be the only posted values)

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'post'){
   foreach( $_POST as $question => $answer ){
       $quest_id = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/' , '' , $question );

       //make database query to check answer
       //    $quest_id is the question ID 
       //    $answer is number of the selected answer
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. you are right But how i can get selected value ?

Comment: See how `$_POST[]` looks: `print_r( $_POST[] );` and then you can use a loop.

Comment: can help little bit more. But In your solution. My Question Id still same as static is any solution

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="ques_ids" value="<?php echo $row['ques_id']; ?>" />

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons with same `name` are mutually exclusive that means if you select one, all others with the same name will get deselected. 
So, the solution to your problem is that you give each set of radio buttons for the answers a different name. You can use a counter for that in your `while` loop:

```
 <form method="post" id="submitme">
    <table class="ques_list" border=1 style="width:100%">
    <?php 
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
          $i++;
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row['ques_title']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value_<?php echo $i ?>" value="1" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_1']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value_<?php echo $i ?>" value="2" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_2']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value_<?php echo $i ?>" value="3" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_3']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value_<?php echo $i ?>" value="4" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_4']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="btn-submit" class="btn-submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If one radio button is checked all the others get unchecked.
Group the radio buttons by setting one unique name for the group
Group one:

```
<input name="test">
<input name="test">
```

Group two

```
<input name="test2">
<input name="test2">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give unique name to each question.

```
<form method="post" id="submitme">
    <table class="ques_list" border=1 style="width:100%">
    <?php $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
        $count = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row['ques_title']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value[ <?php echo $count; ?> ]" value="1" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_1']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value[ <?php echo $count; ?>]" value="2" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_2']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value[ <?php echo $count; ?>]" value="3" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_3']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value[ <?php echo $count; ?>]" value="4" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_4']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php $count++; } ?>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="btn-submit" class="btn-submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Result:

https://jsfiddle.net/yvolkan/o5z6q29o/1/

Comment: @KIMB-technologies yes you're rigth.

Answer (score 0):

its problem related to radio button name. You have to assign a unique radio button name for each question.
Here,  I have take a variable for assign a unique name for each questions radio buttons group.

Try this -->>

```
<form method="post" id="submitme">
    <table class="ques_list" border=1 style="width:100%">
    <?php 
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
        $i=1; 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row['ques_title']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value<?php echo $i; ?>" value="1" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_1']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value<?php echo $i; ?>" value="2" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_2']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value<?php echo $i; ?>" value="3" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_3']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value<?php echo $i; ?>" value="4" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_4']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="btn-submit" class="btn-submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Name them different things from question to question.  That way you can select only one per question but it won't uncheck answers from other questions.. When they ALL have the same name it will uncheck any previous buttons.

```
    <form method="post" id="submitme">
    <table class="ques_list" border=1 style="width:100%">
    <?php 
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row['ques_title']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value" value="1" /><?php echo
$row['ques_opt_1']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value" value="2" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_2']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value2" value="3" /><?php echo  $row['ques_opt_3']."<br />"; ?></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="opt_value2" value="4" /><?php echo $row['ques_opt_4']."<br />"; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="btn-submit" class="btn-  submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```